# How do I search the inheritance tree in C++ at runtime?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a template, which adds a specific ability to a class:

```
template <Class ReceiverOfAbility>
class Able : public ReceiverOfAbility, SomeOtherClass
{
...
}
```

Then I have a standard tree-like inheritance:

```
class Base
{};

class Derived1 : public Base
{};

class Derived2 : public Derived1
{};

...
```

But somewhere in the tree there is a "backwards branch"

```
class Derived2WithAbility : public Able<Derived2>
{};
```

Suppose I have:

```
 Base* basePointer = new DerivedWithAbility;
```

How can I cast `basePointer` to `SomeOtherClass` at runtime? `dynamic_cast` does not work. The problem is that there will be a lot of derived classes and I do not know in forward where in the tree does the class inherit the ability. I would need to search in the tree for  the place where the inheritance from `Able` occurs.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I tried to

```
dynamic_cast<SomeOtherClass*>(dynamic_cast<Derived2WithAbility*>(basePointer))
```

But I get:

```
error: ‘SomeOtherClass’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Derived2WithAbility’
```

Any Idea why?

Comment: Templates are a compile time construct. It would make more sense to search in the code for the instantiation ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Able : public ReceiverOfAbility, SomeOtherClass
```

`SomeOtherClass` is a **private** base class of `Able<whatever>`. For `dynamic_cast` to work (i.e. to be able to cast to `SomeOtherClass` successfully), it must be a public base.

Comment: You're right! I used  
class Able : public ReceiverOfAbility, public SomeOtherClass 
and it works! Thanks! I never even realized that inheritance "defaults" to private.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik it defaults to private for classes, public for structs.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I cast basePointer to SomeOtherClass at runtime? dynamic_cast does not work.

You have to use dynamic_cast. If it "doesn't work", then you cannot cast. dynamic_cast will work only if Base class has at least one virtual function (virtual destructur should do the trick).

> I would need to search in the tree for the place where the inheritance from Able occurs.

As far as I know, RTTI does not provide "inheritance" information for classes. However, you might be able to see inheritance information in debugger. Availability of this information depends on debugger, of course.

--EDIT--

you inherit from SomeOtherClass using private inheritance. Make inheritance public, and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I made sure Base has a virtual destructor. However it still does not work.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: Does "SomeOtherClass" contain virtual methods? dynamic_cast won't work on classes without virtual methods.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its a good idea to scan your inheritance tree. See this post about going through vtables and it doesn't even look accessible via your code

http://kaisar-haque.blogspot.com/2008/07/c-accessing-virtual-table.html

I can see this being useful in debugging but you can't count on it in run time.

I think what you are running into is the reason why multiple inheritance is complicated, you have classes that inherit from multiple base classes and so finding a common base class root to point your derived objects can get hairy in these situations.  I don't have a real answer for you other than to maybe rethink your inheritance heirarchy. Can you use composition instead of inheritance and stick to a single inheritance tree?  That would make things much simpler.

Comment: Since C++ doesn't define an ABI taking this approach is not guaranteed to work across compilers or even different version of the same compiler.